# How do you update your project to use the latest version of javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am currently building a new personal React project and would like to take advantage of and play with some of the latest features added to javascript like optional chaining. I have tried including this script in my index.html file  but that did not work. What is the secret to getting the latest stable build of javascript in your React project?
*edit: Sorry I did not add enough information but I am trying to try out the optional chaining feature in Reactjs. However, when I run this even handler it errors out with this error message:

Button.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: props.onClick is not a function

This is true as I wanted to see how the optional chaining works but it is apparently not working here.

```
const eventHandler = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        // other code
        // onClick is the function that is passed from the parent component
        props?.onClick(e);
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript is made to be ***very*** backwards compatible.  If you could add more details around "did not work" we may be able to help.  Right now, we don't know if it's a syntax error, React compatibility error, or something else.  Please see [mre].

Comment: The engine used dictates the available features. In most cases with react, this means the type and version of the browser used (otherwise, nodejs version, engine type and version in general). Some features are not available (yet) on some browsers, no matter the version. Also note, that this implies the end-user's browser is the limit. You can sometimes transpile modern javascript features to older, equivalent javascript (when applicable), e.g. using babel. This is a whole topic on itself though. You should read up on the basics of how javascript is being executed.

Comment: I am using google chrome

Comment: `Button.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: props.onClick is not a function` is not a javascript syntax error, not a missing feature. It looks like an error completely unrelated to the topic you are talking about. You maybe misunderstood what optional chaining does (or doesn't, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I didn't fully understand this syntax until I looked into it.  I didn't know that you could make the call itself optional and thought you could only do it for properties, not methods/functions.  However, you can!  You just need to adjust how you are using the optional chaining.  Write it as:

```
possiblyUndefinedObject?.possiblyUndefinedFunction?.()
```

See [Dealing with optional callbacks or event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Dealing_with_optional_callbacks_or_event_handlers)

> If you use callbacks or fetch methods from an object with a
> destructuring assignment, you may have non-existent values that you
> cannot call as functions unless you have tested their existence. Using
> `?.`, you can avoid this extra test:

Also, be sure to do this in a browser that supports it (Firefox 68 does not work but Chrome 84 does).

```js
const foo = {}

// What you have
try {
  foo?.bar();
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err); // TypeError: foo?.bar is not a function
}

// With ?.() but undefined bar
try {
  foo?.bar?.(); // Doesn't get called
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err); // No error
}

foo.bar = () => console.log("bar");

// With ?.() defined bar
try {
  foo?.bar?.(); // "bar"
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err); // No error
}
```